# How to read different type of NFC Tag in NFCTagReaderSession in iOS 13?

Tags: ios, nfc

For reading NFC Tag UID I am using NFCTagReaderSession in iOS 13. Well it is reading Mifare Ultralight tag successfully. I am able to get Identifier using this code:

```
 func tagReaderSession(_ session: NFCTagReaderSession, didDetect tags: [NFCTag]) {
 if case let NFCTag.miFare(tag) = tags.first! {

            session.connect(to: tags.first!) { (error: Error?) in
                let apdu = NFCISO7816APDU(instructionClass: 0, instructionCode: 0xB0, p1Parameter: 0, p2Parameter: 0, data: Data(), expectedResponseLength: 16)
                tag.sendMiFareISO7816Command(apdu) { (apduData, sw1, sw2, error) in
                    let tagUIDData = tag.identifier 
} } } }
```

Well for this I setup session initialisation as :

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            guard NFCNDEFReaderSession.readingAvailable else {
                return
            }

            readerSession1 = NFCTagReaderSession(pollingOption:  [.iso14443, .iso15693, .iso18092], delegate: self, queue: nil)
            readerSession1?.alertMessage = NSLocalizedString("Hold your iPhone near an NFC.", comment: "")
            readerSession1?.begin()
            } else {
                        print("should do some fallback code")
                    }
```

And it is working fine for Mifare Ultralight. Now I want my app to read all types of NFC Tags that are given in Apple developer site. say :

```
1. NFCNDEFTag
2. NFCISO7816Tag
3. NFCMiFareTag
4. NFCISO15693Tag
5. NFCFeliCaTag
```

well, My question is ... do I need to add any new key in info.plist for these tag?
there is already this key added in info.plist :

```
<key>com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.iso7816.select-identifiers</key>
    <array>
        <string>com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.iso7816.select-identifiers</string>
        <string>D2760000850101</string>
    </array>
```

What are the settings required for all tags??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

```
<key>com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.felica.systemcodes</key>
    <array>
        <string>12FC</string>
    </array>
```

I don't remember the meaning of 12FC value, but you should have it if you try to read `. iso18092`.

I also have the following values for 7816 taken from https://www.eftlab.com/knowledge-base/211-emv-aid-rid-pix/:

```
<key>com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.iso7816.select-identifiers</key>
    <array>
        <string>A0000002471001</string>
        <string>A000000003101001</string>
        <string>A000000003101002</string>
        <string>A0000000041010</string>
        <string>A0000000042010</string>
        <string>A0000000044010</string>
        <string>44464D46412E44466172653234313031</string>
        <string>D2760000850100</string>
        <string>D2760000850101</string>
        <string>00000000000000</string>
    </array>
```

Comment: what about NFCISO15693Tag ?? What should I add for this tag ??

Comment: @rj19 did you manage to know what is the identifier for this tag?

Comment: yes @Erick and as i accepted the answer you can see.